# myClass.System cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java

I get the error: myClass.System cannot be resolved to be a type. - Syntax error on token ";", . expected - Line breakpoint:myClass [line: 19] - main (String[]). Can somebody help?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class myClass {

    public char value[]; // char array called value
    private int offset = 0;
    private int count;

    //private class variable, shared by all String objects
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -684;

    //constructors
    public myClass() {
        value = new char[0]; 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    myClass s = new myClass;
    System.out.println(s.offset);
    }

}
```

Comment: Not about the question, but in Java classes start with a capital letter. Like: MyClass.

Comment: Slightly offtopic, but please note that Java recommends classnames to start with a capital

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
myClass s = new myClass();
```

just missing the parentheses on the call to the constructor